# Microsoft Azure Table Storage: CloudTable() error no suggestions available

Tags: java, azure

I'm using the Azure table storage from java, following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage). I'm successfully able to create a table, add an entity, retrieve an entity and delete an entity. However, I've got this method to delete a table:

```
public void deleteTable(String tableName) {
    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

        // Delete the table and all its data if it exists.
        CloudTable cloudTable = new CloudTable(tableName, tableClient);

        cloudTable.deleteIfExists();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in deleting");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this method I am getting an error on this line

```
CloudTable cloudTable = new CloudTable(tableName, tableClient);
```

which has no suggestions available within eclipse only the following markers:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The constructor CloudTable(String, CloudTableClient) is not visible
> - The constructor CloudTable(String, CloudTableClient) is not visible

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `CloudTable` constructors [`here`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTable.html), you will notice that the code you're using is not a valid one. It is possible that the SDK got upgraded however the code sample isn't. I would suggest using [`getTableReference`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTableClient.html#getTableReference(java.lang.String)) method on [`CloudTableClient`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTableClient.html) to get an instance of `CloudTable`:

```
try
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

    // Create the table client.
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

    // Delete the table and all its data if it exists.
    CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("people");
    cloudTable.deleteIfExists();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Output the stack trace.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```